# SQL count conditioning without the 0 values

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a case count on SQL but I want the results without the 0 how do I do that?

```sql
Select ClubName,
       ClubType,
       Country,
       Concat(Count(case when GameResult like 'w%' then 1 else NULL end), ' ','wins'),
       Count(Case when GameResult like 'l%' then 1 end) AS Losses
  from ClubDim,CountryDim,GamesFact
 where ClubDim.CountryID = CountryDim.CountryID
   And ClubDim.ClubID = GamesFact.ClubID
 GROUP BY ClubName,ClubType,Country,GameResult
Having ClubType = 'Professional'
```

That's the code and I am getting a lot of zeros and my target is to count losses and wins in two separate columns

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "without the 0"?  Do you want to filter them out?  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have put `gameResult` in the `group by`.

More importantly, you need to learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Doing a Cartesian product and filtering in the `WHERE` clause is just awkward.  Not using proper syntax is outdated:

```
select cl.ClubName, cl.ClubType, co.Country, 
       Concat(Count(case when g.GameResult like 'w%' then 1 else NULL end), ' ', 'wins'),
       Count(Case when g.GameResult like 'l%' then 1 end) AS Losses
from ClubDim cl join
     CountryDim co
     on cl.CountryID = co.CountryID join
     GamesFact g
     on cl.ClubID = g.ClubID
where cl.ClubType = 'Professional'
group by cl.ClubName, cl.ClubType, co.Country;
```

In addition:

- Note the use of table aliases.  These should be abbreviations for the table names.
- I did my best to qualify all columns, so it is clear what tables they come from.  Of course, your question doesn't provide this information, so this is just guessing.
- Filter *before* aggregating by using a `WHERE` clause rather than filtering *after* aggregating with a `HAVING`.  Use `HAVING` when you want to filter on the results of aggregations (such as `COUNT(*)`).

Comment: it worked! thank you very much! and thanks for the notes I am still learning sql and all of this is self learned so that's why it's so messy.

Comment: but i just wanted to ask how do you write the query bridged like this and how do I use the abbreviations before columns' names (like cl. and co.)

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously not possible to test without sample data however you should be using `sum` not `count` here. Your `having` criteria should be part of the `where` clause as you are not filtering on an aggregate. I would also recommend using proper `join` syntax which has been standard since 1992! However this should give you expected results, I suspect.

```
Select ClubName,
    ClubType,
    Country,
    Concat(sum(case when GameResult like 'w%' then 1 else 0 end), ' ','wins'),
    Sum(Case when GameResult like 'l%' then 1 else 0 end) AS Losses
from ClubDim,CountryDim,GamesFact
where ClubDim.CountryID = CountryDim.CountryID and ClubDim.ClubID = GamesFact.ClubID
and ClubType = 'Professional'
GROUP BY ClubName,ClubType,Country,GameResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT ClubName,
       ClubType,
       Country,
       CASE WHEN Wins > 0 THEN CONCAT(Wins , ' wins') ELSE NULL END WINS,
       loses
FROM (SELECT ClubName,
             ClubType,
             Country,
             Count(case when GameResult like 'w%' then 1 else NULL end) AS Wins,
             Count(Case when GameResult like 'l%' then 1 end) AS Losses
        FROM ClubDim CLD
        JOIN CountryDim COD ON CLD.CountryID = COD.CountryID
        JOIN GamesFact GF ON CLD.ClubID = GF.ClubID
       where ClubType = 'Professional'
       GROUP BY ClubName,ClubType,Country) X;
```